# Maintaining the hover state background color while hovering its submenu items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a navigation menu with list items `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`.

When a user hovers the list `d`, the submenu items appears inside `d` as `d1`,`d2`,`d3`,`d4` and `d5` respectively.

The `d` menu has a background color on hover, but when the users hover on its sub menu items, the background color of `d` disappears.

What I want is that when the users are hovering the subitems, the hover color should stay on `d` and only disappears once the user mouse outs of its submenu items.

Here is my `code`.

**The JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/mm9QN/

**The HTML:**

```
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">d</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">d1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">d2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">d3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">d4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">d5</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">e</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">f</a></li>
              </ul>
```

**The CSS:**
I am using the twitter bootstrap, so cannot paste the full css code, so below is the link for the same.

http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css

I wanted hover menus instead of click, so here is the code for the same

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

Awaiting Solutions.

Comment: why am I down voted? I had a doubt so I asked a question with all the things required. The down vote should atleast be justified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the dropdown menu is not inside the link, the style that applies when you hover the link doesn't apply when you hover the dropdown menu.

If you apply the hover style to the list item, it will still apply when you hover the dropdown menu, as it's inside the list item:

```
.nav > li:hover { background: #eee; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mm9QN/1/

Comment: Fantastic. It works perfectly on my page. +1 and accepted the answer.